# Align button at centre of Button iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

I have a button whose size may vary as per requirement. But I need the image that is set on it, to always remain at its centre.

The code I'm using right now is:

```
[pAddButton setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [pAddButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [pAddButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

However, when I increase the width of the button, the images stretches automatically. That is what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Are you adding image to button or imageview to button

Comment: I am adding image to button.. Thanks for your answers folks.. the problem actually was that I was setting the image as background image. I removed that and used setImage: forControlState: instead. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code image frame to the button

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.width/2), (self.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting content mode of imageView to centre like this:

```
pAddButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the image using `setImage:forState:` instead of `setBackgroundImage:forState:`.

If that doesn't help you could use `imageEdgeInsets` to reduce the image's width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setImage instesd of setBackgroundImage OR add image as subView on the button [button addSubView:imageView].

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to simply center the image by :

```
myImageView.center = pAddButton.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CGPoint centerImageView = imageView.center;

centerImageView = pAddButton.center;

ImageView.center = centerImageView;
```